# Intercoolerjs on-success not calling js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using intercoolerjs to send a delete request and, if successfull, hide a container.

```
<a href="#" ic-delete-from="/foo" ic-on-complete="hide_deleted_product({{$product->id}})">
   test
</a>
```

This is my Js

```
function hide_deleted_product(id){
  var product = "#product_"+id;
  $(product).addClass('hidden');
}
```

it works fine deleting the item, however, it returns "undefined function hide_deleted_product" in the console. I'm sure everything is fine with the rest of my js code, yet this function won't work.

Comment: Probably a scope issue, but hard to tell without having a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Can you create an example using codepen or similar?  What you have should work fine...